# Why // works in the URL while hitting API using resttemplate in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I saw code written previously in my project by others and they have API URLs as

```
https://example.com:9876//api/v2/getNodes
```

If we look closely, there is a double "/" in the URL. I tried manually in the curl command and it gives me 404 which is correct.
However, in the project, we are firing API using resttemplate and it is working fine. I am wondering how it is working. It should fail ideally. Can anyone have any idea why it is working?

Comment: maybe `RestTemplate` detects and removes the invalid double-slash?

Comment: Initially, I thought of this but today I tried using the same(double slash) and it failed. So really not sure what exactly is happening.

Comment: Well formed URI are allowed to have empty path segments;  see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#appendix-A